# Still Getting Prompted to Install Windows 10 Despite Deletion of $WINDOWS.~BT Folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, unwanted-application

Anyone know how to completely get rid of the Windows 10 upgrade prompt so I can install critical updates? I seemingly deleted all the necessary files and folders including the $WINDOWS.~BT folder but every time I uncheck the optional "Upgrade to Windows Home" update and attempt to install the important ones, I immediately get prompted to install the upgrade now or schedule it for later. Is there something that needs to be deleted or modified in registry to make this go away for good? What am I missing? I'm on Windows 8.1, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

1. Uninstall the Windows Update KB3035583

After uninstall:

2. search for updates (just search, don't install any), select KB3035583, right click and hide it

This way it won't get installed/listed when installing other important updates.

That should work, at least it does for me on a few computers.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. That's the very first thing I did before anything else. The problem is the installation files were already downloaded. They're located in the $WINDOWS.~BT folder which I've already deleted. And despite having done all that I still get prompted to upgrade every time I try to install important updates. I'm in the same boat as this guy here http://superuser.com/questions/950340/how-can-i-call-off-a-windows-10-upgrade the only differences being that I'm on Windows 8.1 and I left the prompt as is without scheduling/confirming a date or time for the upgrade.How to rectify?

Comment: Have you tried the registry changes from this answer?http://superuser.com/a/951309/479081

Comment: I saw that and want to try it but I can't since the registry values of of 8.1 don't mirror Window 7's 100%. Can anyone on Windows 8.1 post the registry of their aborted upgrade before the release of Windows 10 so I can set those values on mine to see if it works?